# Prove that L={$a^p$: p is prime } is not regular using pumping lemma

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language, pumping-lemma

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145675/understanding-about-pumping-lemma-for-regular-language-confusions-of-beginner

This the reference idea I have used in this proof. But I am very clear that my proof is indeed wrong. But I want to learn if there is any way to make this proof right this way? And how am I supposed to do new questions in exam if there is not a working way to solve all proofs? I mean math should be like that no? Are there types of questions that I need to practice in order to be able to solve as many as many problems?

Anyway, here is my proof-:

1. Let $a^p$ is regular

w=$a^n$=xyz

Let y= $a^m$ where m is between 1 to n
Now let i=2.

|$xy^2z$|=|xyz|+|y|=n+m

Here

n+1<n+m<n+n

or n+1<n+m<2n. Is there way to prove that n+m isn't prime based on this equation?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to prove such a thing. You can't limit yourself to a single $i$. But it is possible to prove that for $i=1,2,3,\ldots$, the different $n+im$ can't *all* be prime. In particular, if you pick a prime $p$ that doesn't divide $m$, then $n+im$ is occasionally divisible by $p$.

As for the more general question, there is no magic bullet  for easily learning to solve problems you haven't seen before. Practice. Develop a large toolbox of tricks. Develop a gut feeling for when each trick usually works.

Comment: then how are we supposed to tackle new questions in exam, can you tell about that? are there some basic types of questions to practice in order to be able to solve any problems?(almost any problems in exam).

Comment: @supcem There is no easy answer there, unfortunately.